# Why is it called "under the sea" when it should be "in the sea?"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrases

Why is the phrase "under the sea" constructed the way it is? Shouldn't it be "in the sea?" Does "sea" refer to the surface of the ocean in this case? Or is it just one of those quirks in English?

Comment: Resource: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/955/why-does-under-the-sea-mean-in-the-sea

Comment: The *sea* is just a large body of water. It could be ocean, lake, etc. and your question would be the same. The real issue is *under* vs. *in* vs. *on* vs. *into*, etc. The reference is usually in relation to the water surface. Adding some example sentences to your question would be helpful, as context is often important when deciding on the correct preposition.

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate of a more recent question because it is a subset of that question. I think it makes sense to collect all the answers in one place even though this question currently has a higher score.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Under*** is used to refer to something below a surface:

[Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/under_1) has:

> e. below the surface of water:
>    *The ducks kept diving under the water to catch fish.
>
>   He was the first person to claim there was oil under the North Sea.
>   She jumped in the pool and went under.*