# Right use of prepositions in, on, under in relation to water

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The dictionaries do not provide good enough answers for the right use of these prepositions in the following context:

1. The man is IN  the water.
2. The man is under the water.
3. The man is below the water.

Besides, which of one of these it is correct and why?

- A: The boat is ON the water.
- B: The boat is IN the water.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102578/why-is-it-called-under-the-sea-when-it-should-be-in-the-sea/102585#102585

Answer (score 3):

If you are *in X*, you are surrounded by X on all or most sides.

The surrounding can work vertically (I'm in a cardboard box) or horizontally (I'm in a box I drew on the ground with chalk).

If you are *on X*, X is touching your feet or the bottom of yourself, and X is a surface or something flat.  If X is something flat and you are *on* it, you are generally on the top of it.

If you are *under X*, the "top" of X is generally above your head.  At this point, if X is also surrounding you on all or most sides, you are also *in x*.

Being under X, if X is a surface or something flat, means it is on you, and you can't be *on* it.

Water is both something that can you can have the top of beneath your head, something that can surround you on most sides and is also something that is a flat surface so it works with all these prepositions.

So you can be:

- *in* water,
- *on* water,
- both *in* and *on* water,
- both *in* and *under* water
- but not really both *on* and *under* water.

Answer (score 3):

> He is **under** the water.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dHcn4ZXK450/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>

> He is **below** the water.

can be understood to use "*water*" as a layer which something is underneath

[image]
>The Abyssal Plain and Oceanic Crust is **below** the ocean

> He is **in** the water.

has the meaning of being surrounded, in part or in whole by water. If you are **under** the water, you are also **in** the water.  If part of you is *above* the water's surface, you are **in** the water.

[image]

Of your prepositons, one can only "Splash **in** the water".

> **on** the water.

is usually used to describe a boat during an *activity*, since it is "on the *surface* of the water"

[image]

> The boats are sailing **on** the water.

whereas

> **in** the water

is usually used to describe a *static* position of a boat

[image]
>We took the boat from dry dock and put it **in** the water.  
We launched the boat **into** the water.