# “Floating in” vs. “Floating on”?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, collocations

> - I found 100$ **floating in** the water

Why is “in” placed instead of “on” the water.

I thing they are on the surface of the water not in.

What do you think? [image: money floating in the water]

Comment: Related [Right use of prepositions in, on, under in relation to water](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/131830/)

Answer (score 2):

> *I think they are **on** the surface of the water, not **in**.*

You are incorrect; the bills are **both**.

The phrase *in the water* is idiomatic. If we don't want children to swim, we might say, "Don't go in the water." Even though algae usually floats at the surface, you can see from [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=algae+in+the+water%2Calgae+on+the+water&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) that most writers prefer to talk about algae ***in*** the water, as opposed to algae ***on*** the water.

There would be absolutely nothing wrong with saying the money is *on the water*; the phrase *on the water* means "on the surface of the water," and clearly the bills in the image are floating.

However, your thinking veered into the wrong when you presumed that *in the water* was incorrect; in fact, "in the water" can mean anywhere in the water – submerged, floating, or a mixture of both.

Answer (score 0):

**on** would certainly the right word for most of the notes in the picture because they are on the surface. There are several that are below the surface, though, and **in** the water would be a better word to use.

**floating in water** [does occur](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22floating%20in%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=FH9kWs73N8nivgS2n5_oCg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=648&dpr=1.5), but there are certainly many more occurrences of **floating in space** than **floating in water/the sea/a river**. This is because space does not have a surface to float **on**.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand these two sentences:

1. What's that on the water?
2. There's something floating in the water.

So, you cannot say that one [sentence](https://srinteriortips.com/) is good and other one is wrong. Because usage of prepositions depends on context of the sentences.