# "She is floating in (OR) on the water" when two-thirds of her body is below the water surface?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image: a young woman lying with her arms outstretched on the water's surface]

Is it natural to say, "**She is floating in the water**" or "**She is floating on the water**", when two-thirds of her body is below the water surface?

The dictionaries say "**There was something floating in the river.**" ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/river)) and

"**The boat floated on the calm sea.**" ([source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/sea))

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154317/floating-in-vs-floating-on

Comment: **In** refers to a locale (*river*, *pool*, *sea*), while **on** refers to a substance (*water*). It's possible to say **in** ***the water***, but only if the person is *completely* submerged beneath the surface. That aside, just *floating* (without a preposition or specifying a place or substance) is also fine.

Comment: @JasonBassford no.  Things that are only partially submerged are routinely said to be in the water.  In fact, they're often more likely to be said to be in the water than on it.  Steven Pinker has made some interesting observations about that.

Comment: @JasonBassford "while floating in the water we could still see the city’s buildings peeking over the trees."  Source: https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/30/t-magazine/travel/berlin-lake-swimming.html.  This does not describe someone who is fully submerged.  It may be that you would never use this phrase unless the person were fully submerged, but your preference is not shared by all native English speakers.

Comment: @phoog As I said in another comment before a general cleanup, you can find examples of pretty much anything you want. Even examples of errors, typos, and things that are nonstandard and uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In" is fine in this context, "on" would tend to suggest that the object is mostly out of the water. But you could hear "on" being used in similar situations too. There is a lot of fuzziness, and both "in" or "on" are quite acceptable in many situations.

It would be more likely to say "floating in the pool" rather than "in the water", as  "water" is assumed. In this case "in" is more likely, unless you specify "surface" as in "there was a stick floating on the surface of the pool".

Comment: I (AmE) would normally expect to hear *in the pool* (i.e., the geographical location) but *on the water* (i.e., at the top), although *in the water* wouldn't be jarring.

Comment: As a side note, you can be "in" a pool or "above" it, but generally not "on" it. This is (probably) because the pool is more than just the water, it's also the structure surrounding it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No English variety would have: floating **on** the pool, IMO. Floating on the surface of [a liquid].

Answer (score 4):

***Neither.***

**One just says: She's floating.**

As opposed to doing the crawl or doing the breaststroke.

**In terms of swimming and associated skills.**

Now, **in terms of description**, if you say *She is floating in the pool*., she is obviously not **floating in the river or in the sea**.

John: Where's Jean? Is she in the pool?
Mary: No, look, she's down there **floating in the sea**.
John: Yes, she loves to float, rather than actually swim.
Yesterday, we went down to the river. And there she was! Floating in the river.

- A swimming skill: floating
- Stuff (objects) that float: Balloons and floating mats (the latest craze!) and pool rafts float **on water**, for example.
- Scum and industrial waste floats **on (the) water** (horrible).
- And when someone finds a dead body in the water, one would describe that as: the body was found floating **in the water**.
- Lobster pots do not float in the water, they sink to the bottom of the ocean, for example.

In reference to people in swimming pools (or ocean or rivers or lakes) in terms of swimming:

Learn to float, floating, the skill, staying afloat, and by the way, she shows you how to float face down, too!:

[floating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sS0PZSrI-GI)

- We love floating in the sea, never **in pools**. If you are specifying, the word is **in** for a person. But as I said, regarding pools, people generally just float. And we would not specify.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108478/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-she-is-floating-in-or-on-the-water-when-two-t).

Answer (score 0):

When your mouth and nose stick out, you are floating *on* the water. When they are not, you are floating *in* the water. The essential thing is that you are far enough out to survive. Dead bodies are sometimes floating *in* the water.